# Gulp delay task

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I am trying to use gulp to do the following task:

```
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

watch(['public/app/**/*.js','!public/app/**/*.min.js'],function(){
    runSequence('compressjs','bs-reload');
});
```

The problem is it runs the browser reload too soon. How can I get a delay before it run the next task?

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](http://schickling.me/synchronous-tasks-gulp/) out.

If you need tasks to complete in synchronous order you can inform a gulp task of its dependent tasks.

Example:

```
gulp.task('bs-reload', ['compressjs'], function () {

    //bs-reload depends ^^^^^^^^^^^^ on compressjs. 

});
```

And thus the dependent task will take precedence.